# Bypass need for a trusted document?

Tags: excel, vba, security

Im working on building out a VBA-based app that will have around 150 users. They will all have their own data files, tables, custom views, etc. But I will need to regularly update the code behind the app. So Im using the two-workbook technique where their unique User Workbooks (call them the UWs) all pass control to a Code Workbook (call it CW) which contains all the code. That way, when I need to update, I update the CW, and everyone simply replaces the old CW in their folders with the new one and their UWs remain the same.

My problem is that I'd like the CW to essentially remain hidden and protected. But with macro security, when they open their UWs after the update and it immediately calls the startup subroutine in the new CW, it won't run. They have to first open the CW (which I don't want!) and make it a trusted document before opening their UWs will run the startup subroutine in the CW.

It shouldn't matter, but here is the only code in the UWs (note this is still in prototyping/early stages so everything is called 'Test'!):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next
 Workbooks("Test CW.xlsm").Close
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Checks to see if TestCW is present next to Test UW
On Error Resume Next
X = Workbooks("Test CW.xlsm").Name 'Sets X to name of workbook; if its not there this will throw an error and Err <> 0
If Not (Err = 0) Then  'If there's no error
    On Error GoTo CWFileError
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Test CW.xlsm"  'Opens Test CW if in same folder

    'Makes Test CW hidden
    Workbooks("Test CW.xlsm").Windows(1).Visible = False
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Runs test module in Test CW, then returns control to here
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Run "'Test CW.xlsm'!ThisWorkbook.TestStart" 'Uses ThisWorkbook.TestSTart as TestStart is a Workbook-level subroutine in the ThisWorkbook module
End With

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Exit Sub

CWFileError:
MsgBox "Your SVEDash application file named Test CW is not in this folder." _
    & vbCrLf _
    & "Please locate your current SVEDash application file and place it in this folder." _
    & vbCrLf _
    & "This file will close to prevent damage to your data."
On Error GoTo 0

ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Any ideas on how I can bypass this security issue without the users having to change their security settings?

Comment: Can they just add a trusted locaion to where the file is stored?

Comment: "it won't run" - what exactly do your users see when this happens?  When opening an Excel file via code you typically won't see any security prompt, so what do they see ?

Comment: For some reason it was telling me the macro didnt exist or couldn't run at first, but apparently as long as I keep the name of the new updated file the same it will remember the previous trusted status so the updates don't give that error anymore. Weird. If this becomes an issue again I'll look into using a trusted location--not sure what that is but thats how we learn! Thanks. Now I have to figure out how to close this question...still new here...

Comment: You can post your update as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Not an answer,  but have you considered implementing your code wb as an addin?

Comment: Yes, and we decided not to, for a couple reasons. Mostly I'm still new and I'm semi-comfortable doing it this way so we can get it deployed quickly. Thats on the table for the future once I learn how!

Answer (score -1):

This seemed to only be an issue with the first 'Updte'. As I copied newer 'updated' CW into the folder, as long as I kept the name consistent the previous trusted status of the former file with that name was remembered. Hopefully thats an actual solution